# Build error while doing lazy loading of modules

Tags: angular, typescript

While doing lazy loading of a module in another module, getting build error. The lazy loading works fine while doing the ng serve.

Angular version :11.1.2

[error] Error: When building multiple chunks, the "output.dir" option must be used, not "output.file". To inline dynamic imports, set the "inlineDynamicImports" option.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please export lazy loaded modules in public-api.ts

Comment: Could you please elaborate? or add an example? I am adding module to the `projects/lib-name/src/public-api.ts` (to both, module which is going to be lazy loaded, and to `public-api` of the module which is loading the module) but still I am getting this issue

Comment: Yes it fixes the issue, but after adding lazy module into public-api.ts it becomes a part of main chank js. So lazy component becomes not lazy, so isuue is gone. Congrats! ((

Answer (score 0):

As one of developers of ng-packager said:
`Libraries shouldn't contain any lazy-loaded module or routing. These are the responsibility of the application.`

That is means you need somehow move lazy part of you library into another library, and lazy load it from application or from you library where you removed code.

https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/1960#issuecomment-827543254