# Angular CLI throw error when a library has routing lazy loading syntax and try to build it. Any help on this is appreciated

Tags: angular-ui-router, angular-cli

[image]

Compiling with Angular sources in Ivy partial compilation mode.(node:28784) [DEP0148] DeprecationWarning: Use of deprecated folder mapping "./" in the "exports" field module resolution of the package at C:\src\spaexample\axcess-spa-mainapp\node_modules\tslib\package.json. Update this package.json to use a subpath pattern like "./*".

✔ Compiling with Angular sources in Ivy partial compilation mode.
✖ Bundling to FESM2015

**Invalid value for option "output.file" - when building multiple chunks, the "output.dir" option must be used, not "output.file". To inline dynamic imports, set the "inlineDynamicImports" option.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this answer :
[Build error while doing lazy loading of modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69257652/build-error-while-doing-lazy-loading-of-modules)

You need to export the lazy loaded modules in the public-api.ts.